# when to use "myself" and "by myself"

Tags: grammar, reflexives

I have 2 questions

1. When to use "myself" and "by myself"
2. Can I write "my{space}self" instead of "myself"?

Answer (score 1):

***Answer for "1.:"***

Firstly, "myself" is a pronoun that is used to "refer to the person speaking or writing."

Example: "I, myself, will carry the bag."

Secondly, "by myself" is an idiom that meanss "with no one else present" or "without the help of anyone else." As you can see, they both differ (:

Example: "I carried the bag by myself."

***Answer for "2.:"***

No, you cannot use "my self" in place of "myself" because "my self" is not a word.

Sources:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myself
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+myself

Comment: From [Dozy at English test.net/forum](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic87228.html): 99.9% of the time, "my self" is a mistake for "myself". However, it is not completely impossible for "my self" to be correct in the sense of "my being", or "the thing that is me".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I agree, but it is difficult to produce a sentence which illustrates that.  Perhaps "I couldn't swim with a camera round my neck, so I decided that of the two my self was more important".

Answer (score 0):

1. By myself means alone; if I am by myself in a giant cheeseburger factory, I am alone in said factory or I am the only person there that I know.  Myself is just a normal reflexive pronoun.  So

> I ate by myself

means that I ate alone, and

> I ate myself

means that I ate my own body (and was probably alone for most of it anyway).

2.You can write my self, but why would you so that when myself is the correct form of the pronoun and easier to write?